# Spring Integration - SFTP Inbound Adapter to S3 bucket instead of filesystem?

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to wire an SFTP Inbound Channel adapter to use S3 backed storage instead of the local filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take a look a bit to different solution - `SftpStreamingMessageSource`:

```
/**
 * A message source that produces a message with an {@link InputStream} payload
 * referencing a remote file.
 *
 */
public abstract class AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource<F>
        extends AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource<InputStream> implements BeanFactoryAware, InitializingBean {
```

Using this *streaming* solution you indeed won't need a local filesystem for storing temporary files what is use in case of plain `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-streaming

And yes: that isn't possible to replace built-in `FileReadingMessageSource` with some other solution to store temporary files where we read the content from the SFTP files.